# how to combine different qr codes to get a new qr code

Tags: algorithm, qr-code, error-correction, reed-solomon

I want to have 14 different qr codes, where the white boxes are transparent. Then I print it on a transparent paper, and if I put a white paper behind it, I can scan it normally.
I want to be able to take any 2 of these 14 qr codes printed on a transparent paper, put one on top of the other and then behind them a white paper, and get a new valid qr code with a unique value for each combination of 2 codes from the original 14 codes.
The encoded value should be something readable by a person (the user should copy the value manually, so preferably it's a short text).

How do I find these 14 values that should be encoded in the original qr codes? I have an idea, but I still need to solve the error correction code issue.

Answer (score 2):

If we violate the QR encoding standard slightly by fixing a mask (which in practice the decoders won't validate), we can do this without intentional error correction failures, on the lowest error correction setting. There's a bit of slack (but not too much, I think, unless the error correcting code has more structure than I could imagine), so maybe someone else could do one or more of the following:

- Make each payload a URL.
- Increase the error correction setting.
- Shrink the image a bit.

I'll describe at a high level what I did below, but the code is too long for me to want to post on Stack Overflow, so I uploaded it to https://github.com/eisenstatdavid/pairwise-qr-codes.

Mostly, we can think of a QR code as a fixed frame surrounding a payload. We can think of the payload as a linear-algebraic vector over the finite field GF(2), consisting of some data bits and some error correction bits. We want to find 14 vectors such that

1. For each pair of vectors in the set, the bit-wise OR of that pair is a valid payload.
2. Each pair of vectors in the set has a unique OR.

The error correcting code specified by the QR code standard is a Reed--Solomon code, a linear code, which means that the XOR of two valid payloads is always a valid payload. So, the most straightforward way to proceed is to look for 14 vectors with pairwise disjoint support, since every pair of pairwise disjoint vectors has OR = XOR.

One way to do *that* is to apply linear algebra over GF(2) and observe that, if there are k error correcting bits, for every subset of k + 1 positions in the vector, there is a nonzero vector supported on a subset of those positions that is a valid payload. If the vector has n ≥ 14 (k + 1) bits total, then, we're golden. In practice, ≈ 7 k should suffice since the nonzero vector typically only sets half of the positions on which it could be supported, and we can reuse the unset positions.

Even on the lowest error correction setting, however, we don't seem to be able to get that kind of efficiency with a reasonably sized QR code. 1. In the construction above, for each vector, we can expect about half of the k + 1 positions to be set, so naively I would imagine that we could get a 2x improvement by carefully overlapping the subsets by using a constraint solver or maybe just local search.

The squeeze that puts us into a feasible rate is to use non-adaptive group testing. 9 tests suffice to distinguish pairs of 14 items, and 10 is attainable by a greedy algorithm that always chooses the test minimizing entropy.

Pretty pictures below:

[image: Montage of 14 QR code transparencies]

[image: Sample OR of a pair of transparencies]

Comment: That was more or less my plan. And about the mask, I wanted to create much more than 14 qr codes that meets the definition, and choose 14 that use the same mask.

Comment: @RonyTesler I think getting a lot more than 14 will be ~ impossible unless you lean on the error correction.

Comment: Maybe I can take those with the second best mask pattern, maybe the score it gets is not far from the best mask.

Comment: I'm still on it, I edited the question, I added: "The encoded value should be something readable by a person (the user should copy the value manually, so preferably it's a short text)."

Comment: @RonyTesler You could most likely switch it to digits like [Russ Cox](https://research.swtch.com/qart) did, but there would be a lot of them. Since there needs to be 14 transparencies, that limits how much we can improve without a significant new insight.

Comment: Maybe we can ignore some of the error correction modules? Do the scanners treat all the data in the same way and use the EC bits to reconstruct the data and the data to reconstruct the EC (if needed for some reason)?

Comment: @RonyTesler abusing the error correction is a definite possibility, but it turns the nice linear algebra into an NP-hard [lattice problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem). Would users have to enter the whole series of digits? Probably the first few would distinguish the 91 pairs.

Comment: It would be better if the user just sees a short text instead of seeing a long text and have to be told to use only the first K chars.

Comment: another thing - in a masked module we have a problem if we want to use different bits: if one QR is 1 on that module and the other is 0, after the mask they'll be 0 and 1. After the reader decodes the QR, they'll be 1 and 0 again. If we stack them together, their OR operation will give us 1, and after scanning the module, we'll get 0, but we want to get 1 after decoding. Se we have to use the same bits on all masked modules, both in the data and in the EC.

Comment: It's not possible to do an OR that will be identical to XOR because the encoding indicator and the message length indicator are part of the data that needs to be XORed, and it must have dark modules in the same position for all qr codes, and these will produce a dark module in the OR operation, while the XOR should give a white module.

Comment: @RonyTesler That stuff is in the "fixed frame" not the "payload" (scare quotes for my terms, not standard).

Comment: I looked here: (https://dev.to/maxart2501/let-s-develop-a-qr-code-generator-part-ii-sequencing-data-4ae, https://dev.to/maxart2501/let-s-develop-a-qr-code-generator-part-iii-error-correction-1kbm), https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/error-correction-coding#step-8-generating-error-correction-codewords and also at the source code of the python qrcode package, and both encoding and length indicators are used for error correction code calculation. They're part of the message polynomial.

Comment: @RonyTesler They're fixed, doesn't matter.

Comment: They're fixed and will be the same for all the codes (assuming all are the same length and encoding). But it's not possible to use "error_code(data1) XOR error_code(data2)  = error_code(data1 XOR data2)" because we can't XOR the data (we can't XOR the encoding indicator part and message length part of the data).